# How to loop through javascript array and display only part of array then repeat

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm having trouble getting my head around this.  I have a single array of lets say 150 items.  I only want to display 50 at a time.  So, I'll have a button at the end of the display that says something like: "Display 51-100".  OnSubmit of this button, javascript code displays 51-100.  Ditto, next 50.  Suggestions most appreciated!

```
         for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ){
     document.getElementById("comment" + i).innerHTML = commentBody;
```

}

HTML where item needs to be written:

```
    <div style="clear:both"> <br> </div>
    <div  id="flapBox13" class="flapBox">
      <p id='whenFlap13' class="mscFlapTime"></p> 
      <b  id='flapSum13' class="mscFlapSumBold"></b>    
      <p     id='flap13' class="mscFlapText"></p>            
    </div>
```

Comment: Set a variable `pagenum`, and display items `pagenum*50` through `pagenum*50+49`. When they click the button, increment `pagenum` and display the appropriate range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an list of 150 items. Let's give it the autological name `list`. First we'll write a function to divide a list into several lists:

```
function take(n, list) {
    return list.slice(0, n);
}

function drop(n, list) {
    return list.slice(n);
}

function concat(lists) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply(this, lists);
}

function divide(n, list) {
    if (list.length) {
        var head = take(n, list);
        var tail = drop(n, list);
        return concat.call([head], [divide(n, tail)]);
    } else return [];
}
```

Now we'll divide your `list` into pages of 50 elements each:

```
var pages = paginate(50, list);

function paginate(n, list) {
    return divide(n, list).map(function (items, index) {
        var number = n * index;

        return {
            start: number + 1,
            end: number + items.length,
            items: items
        };
    });
}
```

Now let's look at some HTML:

```
<h2 id="pageHeader"></h2>
<ol id="pageItems"></ol>
<div id="pageButtons"></div>
```

Now that that's out of the way let's write some more JavaScript:

```
var header = document.getElementById("pageHeader");
var items = document.getElementById("pageItems");

function displayPage(page) {
    header.innerHTML = "Items " + page.start + " to " + page.end + ":";

    items.start = page.start;

    items.innerHTML = "";

    appendChildren(items, page.items.map(function (item) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = item;
        return li;
    }));
}

function appendChildren(element, children) {
    children.forEach(function (child) {
        element.appendChild(child);
    });
}
```

We'll display the first page by default:

```
displayPage(pages[0]);
```

Next we'll create a bunch of buttons:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById("pageButtons");

appendChildren(buttons, pages.map(function (page, index) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", display);
    button.innerHTML = index + 1;
    return button;

    function display() {
        displayPage(page);
    }
}));
```

That's all folks. See the demo for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/EHfn3/

Comment: Aadit.  Awesome!  Thanks so much.  I looked and looked for how to do this properly. I couldn't find anything.  Hopefully this will help many others who are trying to do the same.  Thanks!

Comment: Aadit.  This is great.  I never would have gotten here on my own.  Got it working.  Great.  Thanks.

Comment: Aadit:  I'm trying to understand how to use your code given the (to me) complex HTML and CSS structures I am writing to.  I'm having trouble how to insert the HTML code I added to my question above.  As an example, I used HTML for item #13.  Obviously what I am trying to replace is those 50 HTML statements and use document.createElement("li") instead.  Many thanks!

Comment: @hypermiler I'm not really sure. There's not enough information in your question for me to be able to debug it. How about you make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ and I'll see what I can do to debug it.

Comment: OK.  Created a new fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/hypermiler/R7SVg/ ), I'm thinking that if you can answer a simple question, it might help me get started.  For example, if I wanted to add a <br> between each item...  how would I do that?

Comment: @hypermiler You should probably ask your doubt as a new question if you want a comprehensive answer. To give you a hint take a look at the following function `intersperse`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse It's in Haskell but the documentation is easy to understand and the function itself can be easily implemented in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

// part is a number

```
function displayArrayPart(myFullArray, part){

  var partToDisplay = part;
  var partOfArray = '';

  for(i=0+(partToDisplay*50);i<50+(partToDisplay*50);i++)
  {
    partOfArray+= 'someHtml'+myFullArray[i]+'someHtml';
  }
  $("#idFromMyHtmlElementWhereIsDisplayedTheArray").html(partOfArray); //jquery

}
```

Comment: I've seen this before and didn't know what it meant, but what is the "+=" notation mean?

Comment: myVariable += Something is the same has myVariable = myVariable + Something